# Why does my encoding add \0 efter decoding?

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, tcp, buffer

So I am sending a simple string from my TCP Client to my server and then when I receive it it decodes the bytes and prints out what it got.. However I am sending

`Client connecting..`

and I receive

`Client connecting..\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0`

Why is that?
The buffer seems to be the same, 18 bytes with the empty ones being 0
is this due to the Encoding method? I've tried different ones likes `Default` and `UTF8` but it seems to do the same still.

```
    _listener.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection..");

    //Assign our client the value of the first accepted request.
    _client = _listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    Console.WriteLine("Client connected.");

    //Set the stream to listen for incoming requests.
    _stream = _client.GetStream();

    //Build the package
    byte[] buffer = new byte[128];

    var bufferLength = _stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    return buffer;
```

And it passes the byte array to this

```
    public void SendPacket(byte[] buffer)
            {
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostName, portNum);

                NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();

                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.WriteLine($"Received from remote client: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)}");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine($"Relaying to the remote server: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)}");

                ns.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        }
```

And then

```
Console.WriteLine("Data Received..");
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, length);
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
Console.WriteLine("Received: " + data);
```

Comment: You're ignoring the `bufferLength`. It prints all the zero's after your data in your buffer.

Comment: Oh, wops...  I forgot about that haha thanks!

Comment: @tkausl that should be an answer IMO; sometimes answers are short and sweet :)

Comment: let me edit the question

Comment: There, I added what it does with the bytearray when it returns, it's passed through the method as a parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your code

```
var bufferLength = _stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
return buffer;
```

`bufferLength` is dropped on the floor.

```
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, length);
```

I don't know where `length` came from, but I suppose it's the buffer's length. Since the receive didn't fill up the whole buffer but only part of it, you must use `bufferLength` to know how many bytes to work with.

Same problem here:

```
var eh = ns.Read(newBuffer, 0, newBuffer.Length);
var received = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(newBuffer, 0, newBuffer.Length);
```

Use `eh`!

```
var eh = ns.Read(newBuffer, 0, newBuffer.Length);
var received = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(newBuffer, 0, eh);
```

Answer (score 1):

\0 is the "empty" value for a char object, so most likely it is reading the chars.